pgfplots: plot with large range of y values not possible with ymax
i ran into the following problem:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ]

        \addplot coordinates {
            (100,2)
            (200,10)
            (300,1e3)
            (400,1e14)
            (500,10)
            (600,2)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

works absolutely fine.
But if I specify the maximum y value, I receive an error:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ymax=30]

        \addplot coordinates {
            (100,2)
            (200,10)
            (300,1e3)
            (400,1e14)
            (500,10)
            (600,2)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Namely:
Package PGF Math Error: You've asked me to divide 162.000000000' by 0.0', but I cannot divide any number by 0.0'. Package PGF Math Error: You've asked me to divide 195.000000000' by 0.0', but I cannot divide any number by 0.0'.
Package pgfplots Warning: Axis range for axis y is approximately empty; enlarging it (it is [0.0:0.0]) on input line 17.
Arithmetic overflow.
What does that happen? How do I circumvent that?
Thanks!

with (300,1000) (400,3000) is not enough?

I can't just change the data, the data is a given, I need to make the plot work @pascal974

I post an answer

With y filter/.expression
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  ymax=30
  ]
    \addplot [y filter/.expression={y>3000 ? nan : y}]coordinates {
        (100,2)
        (200,10)
        (300,1e3)
        (400,1e14)
        (500,10)
        (600,2)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



That just removes the data point which is of course not what I want

@cedi123 If you add a point with 1e14, the rest of the points will be so squished together that one won't be able to see anything useful.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz that's why I want to limit the yaxis. However, I can't do anything about the data, the data is out of my control

@cedi123  Yes, but so --- which kind of diagram do you want? 1e14 is way out of 30 (with my screen, in the graph above, around Jupiter's orbit, at 600 million km). Please clarify which output you need...
